# Show that there are infinite number of functions $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x)(1-(f(x))dx=\frac12 = \frac14

Tags: integration

I used the Newton Leibniz equation to solve for the following definite integral,

$$\int_0^1 f(x)(1-f(x))~dx = \frac{1}{4}$$

To use Newton's equation I first let $x=1$ and therefore replaced the 1’s with x wherever appropriate to give the following,

$$\int_0^x f(t)(1-f(t))~dt = \frac{x}{4}$$

Then I applied Newton’s formula to give the following,

$$\frac{d(\frac{x}{4})}{dx} = f(x)(1-f(x))*(\frac{dx}{dx}) -f(0)(1-f(0))*\frac{d(0)}{dx}$$

This implies,

$$\frac{1}{4} \ = \ (f(x)(1-f(x))$$

Now substituting $f(x)=Y$ to give,

$$Y^2 - Y + \frac{1}{4} = 0$$

giving, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.
However I not able to find any other function other than this constant function. I found this question while practising some past papers of CMI, it would be great if some one could elucidate this problem.

Comment: Can you please use MathJax to format your equations. It's very hard to read otherwise.

Comment: The redundant parenthesis also make it harder. ((f(x)(1-(f(x))))? Really? f(x)(1-f(x)) is way more readable. And $f(x)(1-f(x))$ is even better.

Comment: Changing the value of a function at one point does not change the value of its integral, so you can just choose $f(0)$ to be anything and $f(x)=\frac 12$ if $x \neq 0$.  This is an infinite set of functions that work.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$0 \le \left(f(x)-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = f(x)^2-f(x)+\dfrac{1}{4},$$ and thus, $$f(x)(1-f(x)) = f(x)-f(x)^2 \le \dfrac{1}{4}$$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Hence, $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)(1-f(x))\,dx \le \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{4}\,dx = \dfrac{1}{4},$$ and equality holds if and only if $f(x)(1-f(x)) = \dfrac{1}{4}$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, i.e. $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. If you assume that $f(x)$ is continuous, then $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)(1-f(x))\le\frac14$$ always holds. Hence, $f(x)(1-f(x))<\frac14$ can be true on any set of null measure.